# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: web3js, javascript

I am trying to run the follow code that queries an address to track the balance of an ERC 20 Token through the chain's. Eventually I plan on running a big array of account through all the blocks track balances for every account that has ever owned this token.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(`http://some_url`);


const contractAddress ='some_contract_address'
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);


const address ='0x6C1F09F6271fbE133Db38DB9c9280307F5d22160';


for (var i = 0; i < 8444182; i++) {
    contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call(null, i, (error, balance) => {

    contract.methods.decimals().call((error, decimals) => {
    //   balance = balance.div(10 ** decimals);
      console.log(balance);
    });
  })};
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [14889:0x103000000]    72963 ms: Mark-sweep 3982.1 (4188.2) -> 3971.5
>   (4191.2) MB, 2127.2 / 2.2 ms  (average mu = 0.121, current mu = 0.031)
>   allocation failure scavenge might not succeed [14889:0x103000000]
>   75158 ms: Mark-sweep 3985.1 (4191.2) -> 3974.5 (4194.2) MB, 2133.7 /
>   2.3 ms  (average mu = 0.076, current mu = 0.028) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> ```
> 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0xa18d83dbe3d]
> 1: StubFrame [pc: 0xa18d83847bb]
> 2: ConstructFrame [pc: 0xa18d838d145] Security context: 0x1836dc99e6e9 <JSObject>
> 3: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [0x1836dc985e91] [native array.js:~87] [pc=0xa18d863daad](this=0x1836988026f1 <undefined>,l=0x18363c5bf0a9
> ```
>
> ,m=40,A=0x1836988028c9 ,w=0x1836988029f1
>   ,v=0x1836988029a1 )
>       4: Join(aka Join) [0x1836dc985ee1] [native ar...
>
> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation
>   failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  1: 0x10003b59c node::Abort()
>   [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node]  2: 0x10003b775
>   node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*)
>   [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node]  3: 0x10017bf4f
>   v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool)
>   [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node]  4: 0x10017bef0
>   v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
>   const*, bool) [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node]  5: 0x100431c74
>   v8::internal::Heap::UpdateSurvivalStatistics(int)
>   [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node]  6: 0x1004338b3
>   v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double)
>   [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node]  7: 0x100430f4e
>   v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector,
>   v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node]  8: 0x10042fd6d
>   v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
>   v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags)
>   [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node]  9: 0x10043854e
>   v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int,
>   v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
>   [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node] 10: 0x100438598
>   v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int,
>   v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
>   [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node] 11: 0x100418d73
>   v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool,
>   v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node] 12:
>   0x1005f247a v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int,
>   v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
>   [/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node] 13: 0xa18d83dbe3d  Abort trap: 6

The error still persists after running

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

I will appreciate any pointers on this. Is there a more efficient way of doing this that will not draw on as much memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
async function run() {
    const decimals = await contract.methods.decimals().call();
    for (var i = 0; i < 8444182; i++) {
        const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call(null, i);
        const actual = new BigNumber(balance + "e-" + decimals);
        console.log(actual.toFixed());
    }
}

run();
```

Comment: Thanks ... I get this error:  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: balance.div is not a function`

Comment: @SamuelDare: Then cast it to `BigNumber`.

Comment: can you please explain how to do this? knowledge of js is very limited

Comment: @SamuelDare: See updated answer.

Comment: and also it doesnt have the blocknumber parameter from the previous question you answered. Thanks alot!!

Comment: using `        const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call({},i);
` but and logging blocknumber and token balance with ` console.log(i, actual.toFixed());`. the values of i is changing as expected, but the balance is static i.e it is only reading the current state

Comment: @SamuelDare: See updated answer.